# How to align text under picture?

Tags: html, css

I want to align text under picture like this:

[image: right]

Before I had it like this, which is wrong:

[image: wrong]

My code:

```css
.test{
  display:inline-block;
}
.test img{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="test"> 
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" alt="asd" width="316" height="316">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
    make a type specimen book. 
</span>
```

In localhost it somehow only aligns the first line to the image. How do I align all of text?

Comment: you mean inside the picture?

Comment: My first suggestion would be to wrap your text in `<p>` tags, before attempting to style the paragraph.

Comment: No, I need text under the picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your `span` a flex display and provide it with a width.

```css
.test {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 300px;
}
.test img {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="test"> 
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" alt="asd" width="316" height="316">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
    make a type specimen book. 
</span>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vzjj9eLy/

Comment: Thanks, that worked!

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure that the following is what you want, but what about setting the width of the wrapping `span` to be the same with the image?

```css
.test{
  display:inline-block;
  max-width: 316px;
}
.test img{
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<span class="test"> 
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" alt="asd" width="316" height="316">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
    make a type specimen book. 
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.test{
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.test img{
  display:block;
  width:200px;
}
```

```html
<span class="test"> 
    <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png?v=73d79a89bded&a" alt="asd" height="200">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting 
    industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since 
    the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to 
    make a type specimen book. 
</span>
```